# How to add information on button of toolbar?

Tags: winforms, toolbar

I am working on toolbar of word processor.  Usually when we click on any button of toolbar it provides us information of what this option does.

How can I add this feature in my application?

Comment: Please provide more information on the environment, language, and context of what you are trying to do.  There's not enough here for anybody to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the limited info provided, it sounds like you are looking to add the [`Tooltip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx) Class.

Adding this to you winforms project allows you to add a text that will appear over the button/object when hovered on.

In visual studio you can add it from the Toolbox:

[image]

In you application it would appear like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, i want exactly this, Thanks

Comment: glad it worked.  be sure to mark this as the accepted answer via the checkmark on the left of the answer.